# Remove all rows containing certain values from a string

Tags: r, match, rows, grepl

How do I remove all rows from a data frame that contain any of the values I assign in a string vector? I've tried grepl, but that only seems to work when one word is concerned.

```
number <- c(1:5)
text <- c("First text","Second text","Another text here","Yet another one","Last text")
example <- as.data.frame(cbind(number,text))

  number              text
1      1        First text
2      2       Second text
3      3 Another text here
4      4   Yet another one
5      5         Last text
```

Doesn't work:

```
remove <- c("First","Yet")
example[!grepl(remove,example$text),]
```

Desired outcome:

```
 number              text
1      2       Second text
2      3 Another text here
3      5         Last text
```

Comment: @Jaap this question is duplicate to which other question? Please link

Comment: @abhishah901 see the top of the question .....

Answer (score 2):

We can `paste` the elements in 'remove' to a single string separated by `|` (which means `OR`) and feed it as `pattern` in `grepl` for the 'text' column, negate the logical vector and then subset the rows of 'example

```
 example[!grepl(paste(remove, collapse="|"), example$text),]
 # number              text
 #2      2       Second text
 #3      3 Another text here
 #5      5         Last text
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!